# Contact Form 7 showing sent message but not receiving email especially Google aps Domain Emails

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

Experiencing issue with WP plugin, contact form 7. When I fill in the form and submit, I receive a success message stating it was sent  but I received example@gmail.com  but  not received example@companyname.com   google ap's emails     yet I don't receive it in my emails.

Comment: have you checked in spam folder?

Comment: yes i have checks all the folders

Comment: hope this fix the issue, sign in to the Google/Gmail account that you have designated to handle your WordPress contact form emails, then navigate to the "Less Secure Apps" settings page and click the “turn on” button.

Comment: I have tried google Less Secure apps but No Improvements

Comment: have you updated the SMTP option in contact form 7? please visit-https://www.onepagezen.com/configure-contact-forms-wordpress-google-cloud/

Answer (score 0):

This probably has something to do with your server configuration. Can you try sending a mail using [PHP's mail](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function? Is that also not working?

The CF7 plugin also uses this function. What this function does is it sends the mail request to the server. If that request was successful (regardless of whether the mail was send successful) it will return true. There is no other way using this function to check if the mail has actually been sent successful. That's why the CF7 plugin can say that the mail was send correctly even if it hasn't been send by the server.